# Users Being Served Cached Pages of Other Users Accounts

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, http-headers, cloudflare

I have a PHP script which includes a user panel. Inside this user panel there is some information such as their details, account balance, items assigned to their account.

While browsing through the user panel occasionally you will be randomly shown another users account page, but upon refresh it will go back to yours.

I originally thought that there was some sort of PHP session corruption going on, but I began logging all requests (IP of requestor + the user ID). From this I was able to determine that the PHP is never executed when another users account page is randomly/accidentally served. (There was never a log entry from my IP for the "random" account that showed up)

The website uses cloudflare, although I have added a page rule to disable caching for the entire client area.

I have added this which is output for every request made in the client area:

```
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire:');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

In my htaccess file I am using mod_expires with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 0 seconds"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

At this point I have absolutely no idea what else I can do to prevent ISPs/Cloudflare from serving the cached version.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing a cached version of my user panel pages to be shown to users?

The response headers from an occasion where this has happened are bellow.

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
date: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 21:03:30 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
last-modified: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 21:03:29 GMT
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-nginx-cache-status: HIT
x-server-powered-by: Engintron
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 4afd99361e6e3b14-YVR
content-encoding: br
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: Are the url's the same?  If you are using session to pass the user ID (this is a good thing) then they probably are, if you add a Identifier (such as a unique hash) for each user to the URL, then it would probably not cache them as a whole as it will see them as different requests.  Even if this is not used in the PHP at all.  This doesn't necessarily solve your security issues (personally I would not cache it) but ... just thought I would mention it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I do use the session to pass the user ID, and all the urls are the same. I was thinking this would work too, but was hoping to avoid adding an unnecessary  identifier to my urls.

Comment: Also it doesn't really offer any security as someone could still brute force the cached pages even with a obscure identifier.  With sensitive information, it's not enough to protect it.  To be honest I don't use any caching but I do heavy backend stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was Nginx micro caching causing the issue.

Added this and it fixed the issue:

```
if ($host ~ "portal.domain.com") {
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1;
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_STATIC 1;
}
```